# Intellij Idea resource bundle + annotation in javadoc prompt

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I started using Intellij Idea for some time after working for a few years in Eclipse and I'm missing few features in Idea. First one is about resource bundle prompt. When I'm editing java file and I have some string literal in my class when I move my mouse over this string Eclipse is showing a prompt with values that are defined in resources files (for all languages) for this literal string key. Another very similar feature is when I'm move my mouse over a static field imported form other class. In eclipse I can see all annotation for this field so I don't have to enter that other class to see it. In Idea this information is not present. Does similar features exists in Idea or in Idea plugins ?

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the Ctrl key while hovering your mouse over the variable to see the value. The same thing works with resource bundles if there's only a single instance of the key in the bundle, however if you have translations IntelliJ shows "multiple implementations" on hover and requires you to click and pick the one you want to see. There are a few tickets open with JetBrains to fix this usability issue, however they haven't gone anywhere, for example: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-76594

Comment: Yes, I know about it but we use multiple language resource files. I though there is some faster way than entering a file to see annotation for static field or message from resource bundle.